# Update values of pandas dataframe with corresponding value in another dataframe

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have two dataframes:

```
df1

A    B
-------
foo  2
bar  3
baz  4
```

and

```
df2

A    B
-------
foo  40
bar  50
```

And I want the final result to be

```
A    B
-------
foo  40
bar  50
baz  4
```

I can't figure out how to coax `pd.update`, or `pd.merge` into doing this.

Comment: You can try `df1.merge(df2, on =["A"], how= 'inner')` or try `df1.update(df2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, [`DataFrame.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df3 = df2.combine_first(df1)
```

---

```
df3
     A     B
0  foo  40.0
1  bar  50.0
2  baz   4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [pandas update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

```
df1.update(df2)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df1[df2.columns]=df2
```

Please be sure to answer the question. Provide details and share your research!